# localStorage null even after null-check?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, null, local-storage

In my current project I'm using javascripts localStorage in order to store some data. Since this data is parsed afterwards, I need to set it to a default-value if it isn't existing yet. To do so I'm using a simple if-check: Unfortunately, it doesnt work. Here is my code:

```
localStorage.setItem("myItem", null); //Test for the if-check. But even without it isnt working.
    if(localStorage.getItem("myItem") == undefined || localStorage.getItem("myItem") == null || localStorage.getItem("myItem") == ""){
        console.log("is null");
        localStorage.setItem("myItem", "myDefaultContent");
    }
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("myItem")); //null!
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Run `typeof localStorage.getItem("myItem")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you set `localStorage.setItem("myItem", null);` you really set `myItem` to the *string* "null", not `null` type. Remember that `localStorage` value is **always** String. In your case `null` gets converted to string, before it's stored.

So the check

```
localStorage.getItem("myItem") == null || localStorage.getItem("myItem") == undefined
```

is `false`, of course, and default value is never set.

If you set `myItem` to be `"null"` string then you should check against string too:

```
localStorage.getItem("myItem") === "null"
```

Or better, don't set `null` in the first place and null/undefined comparisons will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would never even have thought about that! Everything works fine now.

Comment: You are welcome! Because WebStorage values are strings, to store objects and arrays we use JSON.stringify to get a string and then save it.